# Counting Problem: Baseball problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am self studying statistics and having hard time with figuring this one out.
In a baseball team, there are 15 players on its roster.

1. How many ways are there to select 9 players for the starting lineup and a batting order for the 9 starters?
2. Suppose 5 out of 15 players are left handed. How many ways are there to select 3 left-handed outfielders and have all 6 other positions occupied by right-handed players?

My initial take at the problem for (1) is: ${15 \choose 9}{15 \choose 9}$ but this is not looking right. For (2), I thought ${15 \choose 5}\div 6$ but that is also not right.

According to by textbook, answer for (1) is 659,067,881,572,000 and for (2) 9,072,000

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For the questions you asked, 659,067,881,572,000 and 9,072,000 are completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:  For problem 1, ${15 \choose 9}$ is the number of ways to select the players.  Given the $9$ players, how many orders are there?  For 2, you are selecting three of the five and six of the other ten.

Comment: For 1, there are two orders, right? If not, I guess I am not understanding that part of the question correctly. For 2, would it be (5 choose 3)*(12 choose 6) because we have 12 people left after 3 are chosen?

Comment: For 1, you now have to line up the nine selected players in some order.  This is the number of permutations of nine things.  For 2, you only have ten right handers to choose the six from.

Comment: Oh, then for (a), would it be 15!/9!? And for 2, (5 choose 3)*(10 choose 6)?

Comment: You are correct for 2.  For 1 it would be ${15 \choose 9}*9!$, which equals $\frac {15!}{6!}$.  An easy way to see this is to line up all $15$ players, which you can do in $15!$ ways.  Then play the first nine.  You have $6!$ equivalent orders, because you ignored the positions of the last $6$ players.